# Error in task sequence failure: "Incorrect function: Error 00000001; Source: Windows"

Tags: sccm

I am receiving the above error when running the task sequence and it is failing on the step that is in the picture I provided.  Does anyone have any ideas on why?  I know the error is very generic, and I have tried several things to address it - I checked the box to disable 64-bit, I made sure that the package containing the batch file was referenced in that step, etc.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I am very much a noob when it comes to SCCM.  Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the SMSTS.log saved in C:\Windows\CCM ?

It should contain the reason why this is failing

While looking at your TS, It could be that using a working folder with UNC paths fail the TS because CMD does not support running UNC paths out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cmd /c at the start of the Command Line field. It's quirky, but has often fixed my issues.